# Copying node twice when certain conditions are met in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt question that I'm hoping someone might be able to help with.  I have a list of child nodes underneath a parent.  Certain of these notes have a letter in either in parenthesis or with an open parenthesis.  This means that the variant could be either "on" or "one," for example.

What I'd like to do is separate these out, so that they appear as two separate elements, but I'm not quite sure how to do that with xslt.  Is it possible?

An example is below to give you a sense of what I'm working with.

```
<forms>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on</variant>
    <variant>o</variant>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on(e</variant>
    <variant>o</variant>
    <variant>an(n)e</variant>
    <variant>æn(n)e</variant>
    <variant>en(n)e</variant>
    <variant>en</variant>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on(e</variant>
    <variant>anne</variant>
    <variant>æn(n)e</variant>
    <variant>anre</variant>
    <variant>are</variant>
    <variant>hare</variant>
    <variant>ore</variant>
    <variant>anes</variant>
    <variant>æn(n)es</variant>
    <variant>en(n)es</variant>
</forms>
```

And ideally it would look something like this when done.

```
<forms>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on</variant>
    <variant>o</variant>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on</variant>
    <variant>one</variant>
    <variant>o</variant>
    <variant>anne</variant>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>ænne</variant>
    <variant>æne</variant>
    <variant>ene</variant>
    <variant>enne</variant>
    <variant>en</variant>
    <variant>ane</variant>
    <variant>on</variant>
    <variant>one</variant>
    <variant>anne</variant>
    <variant>æne</variant>
    <variant>ænne</variant>            
    <variant>anre</variant>
    <variant>are</variant>
    <variant>hare</variant>
    <variant>ore</variant>
    <variant>anes</variant>
    <variant>ænnes</variant>
    <variant>ænes</variant>
    <variant>ennes</variant>
    <variant>enes</variant>
</forms>
```

I can copy the nodes fine and suppress the parenthesis when necessary, but what I don't know how to do is create the conditional that would cause it to only copy twice when those parenthesis exist as part of an apply-templates command.

Comment: I don't think the logic for copying twice belongs into the `apply-templates`, it belongs into your template e.g. `<xsl:template match="variant[contains(., '(')]">...</xsl:template>`. Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I'm using Saxon 9.6.0.7.

Comment: I noticed some redundant items in your list. Do you want to preserve those?  It would not be difficult to deduplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes down to some simple logic to check the string value of the `<variant>` content, and then some simple logic to chop up the string as appropriate.

The sample code here works in XSLT 1.0 as well.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="forms">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="variant">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Works in XSLT 1.0 -->
        <xsl:when test="contains(., '(')">
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- Enter the shorter value, minus anything in the parentheses -->
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., '('), substring-after(., ')'))"/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- Enter the full value, only excluding the parentheses -->
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(., '(', ''), ')', '')"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I really appreciate it and you're right, that is simple.  I don't know why I didn't think of it.

Comment: @medievalmatt, re: why, I've had plenty of personal experience with not seeing simple solutions.  :)  A lot of it comes down to time spent in any particular idiom, be it XSL, Python, C++, etc.  Different approaches, different ways of thinking.